# Trocando link conforme input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso criar um `input` de texto que, conforme eu insira uma quantidade, ele mude o link de um botão, mas somente uma parte do link.

Por exemplo, tenho esse link:

```
https://sterilair.vtexcommercestable.com.br/checkout/cart/add?sku=17&qty=1&seller=1&sc=1
```

Quero que sempre que a pessoa coloque 1,2,3,4... no input ele mude o valor `qty=1` do link que a pessoa vai clicar a abaixo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Você irá usar o evento `change` para fazer isso.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#qty").change(function(){
       val = $(this).val();
       newURL = "https://sterilair.vtexcommercestable.com.br/checkout/cart/add?sku=17&qty=" + val + "&seller=1&sc=1";
      // alert(newURL);
       $(".log").append("URL trocada para:<br>"+newURL+"<br>");
       $(".url").attr({href:newURL});
    });
});
```

```css
.log{
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="qty" id="qty" type="number" />

<a class="url" href="https://sterilair.vtexcommercestable.com.br/checkout/cart/add?sku=17&qty=1&seller=1&sc=1">UFL</a>

<div class="log"></div>
```

Dessa forma, sempre que o valor da quantidade for trocado, a *URL* será alterada para a quantidade inserida.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso com jQuery. Por exemplo:

```html
Quantidade: <input type="text" name="qtd"><br>
<input id="botao" type="button" value="Go to Google" />

<script>
$("#botao").click(function() {
    location.href= "https://sterilair.vtexcommercestable.com.br/checkout/cart/add?sku=17&qty="+ $("#qtd").val() +"&seller=1&sc=1"
});
</script>
```

Veja que, de acordo com o que for preenchido no `input`, o script jQuery irá formar a URL.

Comment: Olá luã, irei testar o mesmo pra ver se funciona, mais agradeço desde já ! :D

Comment: Caso você tenha algum problema para implementa ou duvida com o jquery estou a disposição. Boa Sorte

Answer (score 0):

Possível é, afinal de contas, na informatica tudo é possível até que se prove o contrário. Segue a solução abaixo:

```js
$("div#div_do_link #input_link").keyup(function() {
  var value = this.value;
  if (value) {
    var link = "https://sterilair.vtexcommercestable.com.br/checkout/cart/add?sku=17&qty=" + value + "&seller=1&sc=1";
    $('div#div_do_link a#ancora_link').attr('href', link);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div id="div_do_link">
  <input type="text" name="input_quantidade" id="input_link" />
  <!-- Ancora-->
  <a href="" id="ancora_link">Link</a>
</div>
```